# Pyside6 lupdate won't recognise marker "translate", only "tr"

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

I used pyside6 to develop a software, I'm trying to do i18n on it. I found a weird problem with the pyside6-lupdate tool.

When I use the 'tr' marker in my python file, the tool can successfully exact it to a ts file. i.e main.py

```
self.btn_open_file = QPushButton(self.tr('Open File Folder'), self)
```

the command I run in the terminal is:

```
pyside6-lupdate main.py -ts test.ts
```

But when I use it on QT designer generated python files, it won't work anymore, as those files use 'translate' as the marker, shown as below: ui_peg_page.py

```
def retranslateUi(self, PegPage):
        PegPage.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("PegPage", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("PegPage", u"1. Peg to Existing Mapping Column (OR)", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("PegPage", u"2. Create a New Mapping Column", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("PegPage", u"GroupBox", None)
```

When I run the command again, nothing was extracted. I wonder if anyone has encountered the same issue before. My pyside6 version is 6.2.2.1. I tried this on both mac and windows, both won't work. Would appreciate it much if anyone can point me a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use Qt Designer for UI creation you should provide `lupdate` with form file, not a generated python module.

See details in [PYSIDE-1717](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1717) and [PYSIDE-1774](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1774).

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, but I still think pyside6-lupdate should be a legit use in the future, as I have no problem doing this in the earlier version like pyside2 and pyqt5. I think the QT team will fix in the future, pyside6-lupdate definitely can work with these two markers "QCoreApplication.translate" and "tr", it just the "u" unicode marker stands in the way now. Also pyside6-lupdate's "-tr-function-alias" is not working too. I believe it is just not stable yet.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood my comment and/or didn't check jira cases. `lupdate` is legit to use (pyside6-lupdate is the same tool, name just depends on a platform). But you shouldn't use `lupdate` with auto-generated files (created by Qt Designer). You should provide `lupdate` with form-file instead (ui-file).

Comment: With regards to "-tr-function-alias" - yes, this was a bug - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1687
It should be fixed already in recent version.

Answer (score 0):

After many failed trials, finally I found the tweak to fix it. If you want to use "QCoreApplication.translate("hared coded context", u"Text"), remove the unicode prefix "u", it will work.